# Does $F(\alpha) = F + (\alpha)$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha \in K$ for $F$ is a field and $K$ is an extension of $F$. Then $F(\alpha)$ is a simple extension of $F$ i.e. $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest subfield containing $F$ and $\alpha$. **Is it possible to write $F(\alpha) = F + (\alpha)$ where $(\alpha)$ is the ideal generated by $\alpha$?** ($``+"$, meaning the usual addition of ideals in rings) Well,

$$(\alpha)=\{r \alpha: r \in F\}$$

And so altogether

$$F+(\alpha) = \{x+ r \alpha: x,r \in F\}$$

But this is the same as $F(\alpha)$. $\big($or rather, the above is how $F[\alpha]$ is defined, but $F[\alpha] = F(\alpha) \big)$

Have I made any grave error here? This seems intuitively true; I can't find a counterexample. If this reasoning is flawed, please let me know!

Comment: This is not how $F[\alpha]$ is defined. For example, why does $\alpha^2$ belong to your set?

Comment: A field has no non-trivial ideals.

Comment: Also, if $\alpha \in K$ I would interpret $(\alpha)$ as $\{t\alpha : t \in K\}$.  But this is either $\{0\}$ or $K$.

Comment: @AndreaMori and Randall: oh my goodness, how could I have made such a classic blunder? I totally overlooked this elementary detail. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "ideal generated by $\alpha$" is actually the $F$-vector space generated by $\alpha$ inside $F(\alpha)$.

Since $\alpha\notin F$ we must have (using your notation)
$$
\dim_F(F+(\alpha))=2.
$$
Thus the equality $F(\alpha)=F+(\alpha)$ holds for quadratic extensions, i.e. when $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ with coefficients in $F$ but fails for extensions of higher degree.

---

As an example $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}i$ but the set of numbers
$$
L=\{a+b\alpha\,|\,\alpha^3=2, a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}
$$
is not a field since $\alpha^2\notin L$.

Comment: Thank you for elucidating an example in which my reasoning works and one in which it does not!